# When using the summary() function on a Linear Regression Model that has one of the variables as a factor, one of the factors goes missing

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a dataframe that contains a category "AIEasyToUseFactor", whose data is a Likert Scale ranging from Strongly agree to Strongly disagree.

When I try to create a LRM for its relation to how many times AI has been used in the previous month (a category called "HowManyTimesUsedLastMonth"), and then try to produce a summary of it, the "agree" factor from AIEasyToUseFactor goes missing. Any ideas on why this is?

The code:

```
levels(df$AIEasyToUseFactor) <- c("Agree", "Disagree", "Neither", "Str.Agree", "Str.Disagree")

linModel <- lm(HowManyTimesUsedLastMonth~AIEasyToUseFactor,data=df)

summary(linModel)
```

What it produces:

```
Call:
lm(formula = HowManyTimesUsedLastMonth ~ AIEasyToUseFactor, data = df)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-8.731 -4.922 -1.922  0.493 91.269 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      4.922      1.148   4.288 2.69e-05 ***
AIEasyToUseFactorDisagree       -2.547      4.256  -0.598   0.5502    
AIEasyToUseFactorNeither        -3.553      2.203  -1.613   0.1082    
AIEasyToUseFactorStr.Agree       3.810      1.823   2.090   0.0377 *  
AIEasyToUseFactorStr.Disagree    2.442      3.678   0.664   0.5074    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 11.59 on 221 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.04805,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.03082 
F-statistic: 2.789 on 4 and 221 DF,  p-value: 0.02734
```

I'm completely new to R and RStudio so I haven't been able to attempt much bug-fixing by myself, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please see the comprehensive explanation in the linked Q&A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi, This is normal in lm regression function.**

The `Agree` level is supposed to go missing, because it is taken as the **baseline**. If it is preserved in the result, the estimate/coefficient for Agree will simply be 0, and f(Agree) = 0 + Intercept.

ps. all the other levels are compare with Agree to get the estimate, e.g., `AIEasyToUseFactorDisagree` with estimate of -2.547 means Disagree - Agree = -2.547.